# how to customized exception handler in spring boot and jersey

Tags: spring-boot, jersey

I use spring boot and jersey，I want to handle this exception by myself, but spring has a handle exception method. I search method to customized exception handler, but it only suitable springmvc. @ControllerAdvice only match @RequestMapping. If you know how to cancel this autoconfiguration exception handler is also useful.Thank you very very much!

Comment: You need to provide more details. What is _this_ exception? Consider reading [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and revising your question with more detail.

Comment: Check `ExceptionMapper` and friends. As you've noted yourself, controller advice are Spring MVC features. If you chose to use Jersey, you need to look there if they support the features you need.

Comment: I have solved this,  customized exception can\`t handle by       `ExceptionMapper`, I add the customized exception return to application/json, this problem was solved. Thank you for your help!

Comment: This thread might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955584/global-exception-handling-in-jersey